# Some apps in iOS 7 have white text in top bar

Tags: ios

I am facing this issue with few apps, for example in this case with RedLaser. I am sure that this is not a problem with the app since the bar looks fine on other phones (i.e. text is written in black over a white background).

I have tried deleting the app and reinstalling it. I have also tried resetting the iPhone settings (iOS 7.0.3 on iPhone 5). But I am still facing this problem.

Is there some setting in the phones which forces the text to be white for some apps?

[image]

Comment: The white or black writing in the top bar changes depending on what the background is.  Somehow your phone thinks that light gray is dark enough that it should use white writing.  Clearly the wrong conclusion...

Comment: This need to be fix from the developer side, You can post review/feedback to the developer to fix this.

Comment: @OK2B  But others who use the same version of the app don't see this. Its just happening on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way to change it in your iPhone. It is up to the programmer to set the colour of status bar that will be shown. What you can do is to write a review for the app, and it might get corrected in the next version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

As an iOS developer I can tell that this is a setting that the developer made for iOS7.

It's simply a poor design choice.

Comment: But others who use the same version of the app don't see this. Its just happening on my phone.

Comment: Do they have the same iOS version? Restart it or reinstall the app after a restart. iOS 7 is kinda buggy :)

Comment: Haha! I deleted and reinstalled the app. Did a complete reset of my settings too. I still see that. Maybe I will need to reset everything in my phone now!